# Programmatically created new calendar is not visible ,why? in android

Tags: android, calendar, google-calendar-api, android-calendar

I am doing backup and restore of calendars, During restore if calendar is not present in phone(but related account is present), i am creating new calendar with the following code, it has successfully inserted into db (i can see the return value of URI and id). But in calendar application it is visible for an second and disappears,i have no clue what is going wrong, i have made the visible flag with 1 on insertion but still not working.Can someone Help.

```
final String INT_NAME_PREFIX = "priv";
                Uri calUri = CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI
                        .buildUpon()
                        .appendQueryParameter(
                                CalendarContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER, "true")
                        .appendQueryParameter(Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME,
                                mCurrentMirrorItem.ACCOUNT_NAME)
                        .appendQueryParameter(Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE,
                                mCurrentMirrorItem.ACCOUNT_TYPE).build();

                String dispName = mItem.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME;
                String intName = INT_NAME_PREFIX + dispName;
                ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

                if (columnNames.contains(Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME)) {
                    contentValues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME,
                            mItem.ACCOUNT_NAME);
                }
                if (columnNames.contains(Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE)) {
                    contentValues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE,
                            mItem.ACCOUNT_TYPE);
                }
                if (columnNames.contains(Calendars.NAME)) {
                    contentValues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.NAME, intName);
                }
                if (columnNames.contains(Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME)) {
                    contentValues.put(
                            CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME,
                            mItem.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME);
                }
                if (columnNames.contains(Calendars.CALENDAR_COLOR)) {
                    contentValues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_COLOR,
                            mItem.CALENDAR_COLOR);
                }
                if (columnNames.contains(Calendars.CALENDAR_ACCESS_LEVEL)) {
                    contentValues.put(
                            CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_ACCESS_LEVEL,
                            Calendars.CAL_ACCESS_OWNER);
                }

                if (columnNames.contains(Calendars.OWNER_ACCOUNT)) {
                    contentValues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.OWNER_ACCOUNT,
                            mItem.ACCOUNT_NAME);
                }
                if (columnNames.contains(Calendars.VISIBLE)) {
                    contentValues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.VISIBLE, 1);
                }
                if (columnNames.contains(Calendars.SYNC_EVENTS)) {
                    contentValues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.SYNC_EVENTS, 1);
                }

                returnUri = cr.insert(calUri, contentValues);
                long eventID = Long.parseLong(returnUri.getLastPathSegment());
                calid = String.valueOf(eventID);

                Log.d(tag,"calendar name: "+mItem.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME+"\tNew calendar id is: "+calid+"\nInserted URI: "+returnUri);
```

Comment: I found the problem, the new calendars which are created with mail-account cannot be created programmatically, only local calendars can be created.

Comment: @vritplay answer your own question (preferably with a reference to official documents) and accept your own solution! :-)